# When I render in cycles, the color changes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, image, color

I am trying to make some graphics for a game that I have and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I tried looking at the nodes but cannot seem to fix it. What can cause this sort of issue?

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

Comment: You did not embed your images properly. Please use the built-in image adding system next time.

Comment: How would I do that? I am currently just importing a wavefont object

Comment: Agreed! You can drag and drop the images straight into the text field of the question if you wish.

Comment: Not in Blender, in Stack Exchange. That is, your “before” and “after” screenshots were not embedded properly in the question. ‍♂️

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Oh my bad, it should work now! Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

The colors that you see before the render are an object's **viewport color.** This is not its material! It is the color that you view an object as outside of *render preview* mode or *material preview* mode.

When you rendered the image, everything was white because they had no actual texture/material. Go to the material properties and make a new material, and check to make sure it works in the *material preview* mode.

[image]

**Viewport display = the color you see outside of *render preview* mode and *material preview* mode.**^^

[image]

**With no material added, the object is white in *render preview* mode and *material preview* mode.**^^

[image]

**Add a material in the *Surface* section of the material properties panel, not the *Viewport Display* section.**^^

Comment: How would I know which material to add? There are about 50 parts to choose from. Is it more of a add and hope type of thing?

Comment: If you made the objects yourself, you can create your own materials. Select an object and create a new material for that object.